# how to put value in buttons?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code

```
<form action='view.php' method='post'>

<table>

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($check2))
{       
    echo "<tr><td id='td'>",$row['wTitle']," </td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td style='text-align:right;'>",$row['wContent'],"</td><tr><td height='20'> </td><td>    </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='edit'/></td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

and yes, it has edit buttons. but what shall I do to make this happen?:

if there are 3 rows retrieved, there would also be 3 edit buttons that would appear right?

so, if I click an edit button it will take me to another page with a query that would fetch the value of that row. say, I want to make workId as a value of each row. where shall I put it? @_@

it's like

edit button says 'edit' yet it carries the workId value. hooow? T_T
please help the needy mind. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is very crude, but it is one way you can do what you are trying to do:

```
<table>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($check2)) {
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['wTitle']; ?></td>
  <td>Click to edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $row['wContent']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" height="202">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <form action="view.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit" />
      <input name="workId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row[workId]; ?>" />
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and this assumes your `view.php` script looks for the `workId` querystring parameter and if it is present, uses it to edit the record. Your table looks very odd (no headers for example), so you might want to look again at the layout.

One of the better solutions to these Create/Update/Delete requirements is to write a REST API and use AJAX (perhaps via jQuery) to perform them; but I have a feeling this is outside your ability.

Comment: lol. do you read minds? XD thanks for this. will try this now! ^_^

Comment: and yes, I don't use headers. xD and the styles are already in a separate file. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a 'form' with 'action=...' - to surround your submit-button.

or just use a regular link

Answer (score 0):

make it hyperlink and pass id to that page..

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($check2))
{
echo "",$row['wTitle']," Click to edit
",$row['wContent'],"    
Edit";
}

Comment: so, <a href='link' value='$row[workId]'></a> . . .
like this?

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($check2))
{       
echo "<tr><td id='td'><a href='link' value='$row[workId]'>",$row['wTitle']," </a></td><td>Click to edit</td></tr>
<tr><td style='text-align:right;'>",$row['wContent'],"</td><tr><td height='20'></td><td>    </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='edit'/></td></tr>";
}